# How to use dual scroll wheel mouse in Blender?

Tags: workflow, hardware

I've seen some mice with an extra scroll wheel like the [Logitech MX Revolution](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HCT12O). Is it possible to use this in Blender? If so, what is a good use for it?

I currently have a MX518 mouse, which has these buttons

- Left / Right / Middle-scroll
- Resolution switch (pointless)
- Menu button (could be usable)
- Back / Forward button on thumb

I'm about to buy a new mouse now, and I'd like to know if it's any point with two scroll wheels.

Also, I'd like any tips on mice that are recommended to increase effeciency in Blender, for example using multiple buttons for common commands.

Or is it simply better to just have your hand on the keyboard (which I guess I do anyways) on S, G, R, etc?

Comment: I have only one scroll wheel, but it's tiltable, so I use the tilting as back/forward in the browser and undo/redo in Blender. The thumb buttons I mapped to toggle edit mode (back button) and to toggle between solid and rendered view (forward button).

Comment: It depends, is the second scroll wheel recognized as a separate set of buttons by the driver/operating system? For instance, scrolling vertically on my laptop's touchpad generates press/release events for buttons 4 and 5, and scrolling horizontally generates events for buttons 5 and 6.

Comment: That's a very broad question and also highly objective. My first question would be: Do you miss anything when using only one scroll wheel? It also depends on how much you already know about Blender and its control set. For beginners I certainly recommend to stick with the standard control set and layout, because most tutorials rely on them and it certainly gets pretty hard to follow them, once you changed too much. I am pretty content with my Bloody V7. Best 15 Euros ever spent on input devices in 30 years.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky solution could be use AutoHotkey script:

```
*WheelLeft::Send % ((A_PriorHotkey=A_ThisHotkey)&&(A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<20))?"":"{Blind}{F14}"
*WheelRight::Send % ((A_PriorHotkey=A_ThisHotkey)&&(A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<20))?"":"{Blind}{F15}"
```

And then use HorizontalScroll as it was F14 and F15 that is normally unavailable in most keyboards. (it works with modifiers keys also)

Comment: I've found better solution than tht AutoHotkey Script:
[xmousebuttoncontrol](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm)

Its better cause You can specify that only Blender (and other softwares) have specific behavior and other do not.

Answer (score -2):

I personally use a Logitech G602 gaming mouse. 11 programmable buttons and the Gaming Software allows you to create a rather dizzying array of commands and functions which you then drag and drop to assign them to a specific button. It automatically changes to the appropriate profile depending on which program is active. There is also a profile shift command so you can make different profiles for the same program and then shift back and forth between them. I have all my common tasks such as all transformations, toggle edit mode, create object, etc... mapped to specific buttons on the mouse and find that it greatly speeds up my workflow.

Comment: That's very interesting, if it's possible to keep track of all the buttons. However my question was on dual wheel mice, and it's usage. But i'll definitely check out G602 if I can find it in a store.